# How do I turn off auto-aim in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

No joke, this "feature" is starting to get on my nerves, after attacking the mob I'm not looking at when I want to aim at the monster right in front of my face.

Is there any way to turn off auto-aim? Or at least have a way to lock on to enemies?  I searched through the Settings menu and haven't seen any gameplay related way to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to turn off auto-aim? Or at least have a way to lock
> on to enemies?

**No, and no.**

Free targeting is not currently an option in the game for auto-attacks and most Elemental Skills/Bursts. However, some skills feature ground targeting, which you can activate by long-pressing <kbd>E</kbd>, such as Fischl's and Amber's Elemental Skills.

Also, if you are a Bow user, you have the option to activate Aimed Shot by pressing <kbd>R</kbd>, which allows you to control the crosshair and move it exactly where you want to target.

Other than that, targeting seems completely random.